# How to fix errors in python graph packages

Tags: python

I am trying to create a line graph from my data but I keep on getting syntax error from plotnine. It states variable is not defined but it is defined in my dataset. Kindly find below code for assistance:

```
#Filtered data between 2013 to 2015
data_2013to2015 = (pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\kismaiel\\Documents\\data_2013_2015.csv', index_col=0)
          .melt(['Year', 'Month'], var_name='Day', value_name='Temp').dropna()
          .assign(Date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']]))
          .sort_values('Date', ignore_index=True)[['Date', 'Temp']])

# Grouping the data by month and calculate the mean temperature for each month
monthly_avg_temp = data_2013to2015.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')).mean()

# Dropping missing values
newdata = monthly_avg_temp.dropna()

# line graph
from plotnine import *
from plotnine import ggplot

ggplot(data = newdata) + aes(x="Date", y="Temp") + geom_line()
```

PlotnineError: "Could not evaluate the 'x' mapping: 'Date' (original error: name 'Date' is not defined)"